# port forward from lan to lan thought a wan ip

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have a linux router where port forwarding from wan to lan works fine.
But it doesn't work if the request comes from a lan ip to the wan ip

```
br0 interface for LAN (10.0.0.1/24)
eth1 interface for WAN (192.168.137.54)

rule to port forward from 67 to 10.0.0.165:22 

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 67 -d 192.168.137.54  -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.165:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d 10.0.0.165 -p tcp  --dport 22 -j  ACCEPT

iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1445 packets, 212K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MINIUPNPD  all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      icmp type 8
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      tcp dpt:8080 to:192.168.137.54:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      tcp dpt:67 to:10.0.0.165:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 810 packets, 56282 bytes)

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2252 packets, 168K bytes)

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2239 packets, 167K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   809 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain MINIUPNPD (1 references)


iptables -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8806 packets, 872K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      tcp dpt:80

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 96 packets, 45780 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  159 15343 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      tcp dpt:80
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      udp dpt:1900
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10012
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.137.54      icmp type 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     2    --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   35  1694 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:1701
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1701
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1723
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:1723
    0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         udp
    0     0 ACCEPT     114  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
   56  4256 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.165          tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:500
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         udp
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  eth1   br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   58  4408 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 MINIUPNPD  all  --  eth1   !eth1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I think the problem is about return path, wireshark show me:

```
1   0.000000000 10.0.0.129  192.168.137.54  TCP 74  47388 → 67 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1102391743 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   0.004186605 10.0.0.165  10.0.0.129  TCP 74  22 → 47388 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65160 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3263068689 TSecr=1102391743 WS=128
```

How may I forward answers (from 10.0.0.165:22) to correct port (67) ?

Comment: sounds like a hairpinning issue to me. with most routers, you cannot test a DNAT rule from Wan to Lan from the LAN. if you have a sophisticated router you may be able to enable hairpinning, but most do not give you the option to do so.

Comment: Firewalls & routers have distinct paths (WAN to LAN [inbound]; LAN to LAN [local], LAN to WAN [outbound]). For security it doesn't usually do additional 'rules' as your port ward is WAN to LAN, you are wanting something different. As @FrankThomas metioned this is called a [NAT hairpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning)

Comment: Thanks for help, search about NAT hairpin, I found a possible solution adding the rule
 "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -d 10.0.0.165 -j MASQUERADE". Now it is working!